# Mips Help for Converting decimal into octal

Tags: mips

I'm having trouble converting an input (decimal number) and converting into an octal and displaying that number, using MIPS. In the project, I have to use Masking, are there any good sample codes for this?

Answer (score 0):

To mask out all but the bottom 3 bits of the number in `$t0` use:

```
andi $t1,$t0, 0x7    # 0x7 is binary 0111
```